# How to create negative vertical space in tabbing environment?

Tags: line, vertical, tabbing, vspace

I am working on my CV and using a tabbing environment for this. I want a horizontal line between two sections that are in the same tabbing environment. Right now what I have is the code below, but the problem is that the \ \ after HERE creates a white space that I don't want. If I remove the \ \ , the line follows the text rather than staying below it.

```
\begin{tabbing}
{\bf text} \hspace{6mm} \= \hspace{2mm} \= more text \hspace{20mm} \= HERE\\
\rule{19.15cm}{0.1mm}
{\bf text} \hspace{6mm} \= \hspace{2mm} \= more text \hspace{20mm} \= even more text
\end{tabbing}
```

I have tried using negative \vspace like so:

```
\begin{tabbing}
{\bf text} \hspace{6mm} \= \hspace{2mm} \= more text \hspace{20mm} \= HERE
\vspace{-2mm}
\rule{19.15cm}{0.1mm}
{\bf text} \hspace{6mm} \= \hspace{2mm} \= more text \hspace{20mm} \= even more text
\end{tabbing}
```

...but this does not work in the tabbing environment. Is there a (preferably simple) way to fix this?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Could you please create a complete minimal working example?

Comment: What's wrong with applying the optional adjustment following the double backslash at the end of a line, e.g., `\\[-.75\baselineskip]`?

Answer (score 0):

The command `\rule[lift]{width}{thickness}` can do what you want without using `\vspace`. Put different values inside the square brackets and get the result desired.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabbing}
{\bf text} \hspace{6mm} \= \hspace{2mm} \= more text \hspace{20mm} \= HERE \\
\rule[20mm]{19.15cm}{0.1mm}\\
{\bf text} \hspace{6mm} \= \hspace{2mm} \= more text \hspace{20mm} \= even more text
\end{tabbing}

\end{document}
```

[image: Example]

Hope it works as you want!

Comment: Thank you! It works, but this leads to the text on the next line ending up on the right.

Comment: Just put another `\\ ` at the end of the `\rule` macro. I updated the answer. Hope it works as you want now!